# Spring Webflux 2.4.2 - 404 on actuator /auditevents /httptrace /integrationgraph /sessions endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

Small question regarding some actuator endpoints returning 404 please.
I have a web app, based on Webflux 2.4.2, and for testing this issue only, I am using

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Actuator is working, because a curl will get the response for /health /metrics and other endpoints.

However, for those endpoints `/auditevents /httptrace /integrationgraph /sessions`, I am not able to get anything, besides a http 404.

[05/Feb/2021:13:00:18 +0000] "OPTIONS /auditevents HTTP/1.1" 404 141 55 ms

- May I ask what did I miss please?
- What are the steps to enable the /auditevents endpoint please?
- What are the steps to enable the /httptrace endpoint please? I have sleuth and Zipkin working
- What are the steps to enable the /integrationgraph endpoint please?
- What are the steps to enable the /sessions endpoint please?

Those are really the only endpoints returning 404, still do not know why.
Don't want to spam with one question same question per endpoint. All other actuator endpoints are fine.

Thank you

Comment: Spring boot version ?

Comment: from the log line it looks like you are using the OPTIONS http method. I believe you should be using the GET http method for `/auditevents`. If you are using curl to test these endpoints you can pass in `-X GET`

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. But getting the exact same wit -X GET, still a 404

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Spring Boot Reference Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-process-monitoring-programmatically) :

To enable `/httptrace` in the actuator, then you have to create a bean of  `InMemoryHttpTraceRepository` class in the custom `@Configuration` class which provides the trace of the request and response.

```
@Bean
public HttpTraceRepository htttpTraceRepository() {
  return new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository();
}
```

To enable `/auditevents` in the actuator, then you have to create a bean of `InMemoryAuditEventRepository` class in the custom `@Configuration` class which exposes audit events information.

```
@Bean
public AuditEventRepository auditEventRepository() {
  return new InMemoryAuditEventRepository();
}
```

To enable `/integrationgraph` in actuator, you have to add `spring-integration-core dependency` in the pom.xml (as per documentation) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or if you are having a spring-boot project, then add this :

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

`/actuator/sessions` are by-default enabled. But still you can add this explicitly to check the behaviour.

Add this in application.properties.

```
management.endpoint.sessions.enabled = true
```

Comment: Very. Accepted. Many thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: please dont post screenshots of text, include the text in the answer, with a link to the text and use the *quote* functionality. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1840146 quote from link: `You should not post code (or error/exception messages, log files, configuration files, project files, or anything else that is represented in textual form)`

Comment: @Toerktumlare Updated my answer. Removed screenshot.